# Using next and previous button with UITextField, problems with firstresponder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextfield, first-responder

I am using a subclass of a scrollview that moves the keyboard out of the way. (`TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`)

I think this is conflicting with my implementation of the next and previous buttons.  I have built an inputaccessoryview

I have a category that sets the next and previous textfields for each field

when i edit a textfield, i set the current, previous and next textfields

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    _currentTextField = textField;
    _prevTextField = [textField prevTextField];
    _nextTextField = [textField nextTextField];

    return YES;
}
```

when they click next or previous i call this method

```
- (void)selectAdjacentResponder:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmented = sender;
    if(segmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        [_prevTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [_nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

this works fine.. but when i close the keyboard.  my scrollview is messed up.  if i add the line

```
[_currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

to the first line of my selectadjacent method it solves the problem.  but the problem is it makes the screen focus in a funky way since i'm dismissing and accessing the next textfield at the same time.

i have tried resigning first responder when i close the keyboard.  but i think my scrollview is calculated before that point..  any idea what to do =/